# Loop through employee numbers and see if certain date falls within a period

Tags: vba, excel

Who can help a beginner out. I've added two screenshots to make my story clearer.

[image: Calculation]

[image: Projects]

My excel sheet is two tabs. One is 'calculation' and other is 'project'.

What i'd like to know is how to program the following in vba:

In the calculation tab there is a employee number in column E. I have to look if that number also is written in the projects tab. If so i need to know if the date of the calculation tab falls within the start and end date in the projects tab. If so then write the info if that row to the empty columns in the calculation tab.

Another problem arises when an employee works multiple jobs in the projects tab. I guess there needs to be another loop in here:

If the date from calculation tab doesn't fall in the period from start to end in the projects tab, is there another row with the same employee number and maybe it falls within that period.

I hope i made my story clear. I know what the steps should be, just not how to program it. I hope someone is able to help me with this.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I managed to do it by making two loops. One loop for the Calculation tab to go through the rows and a loop in this loop to check if the employee number is found in the Projects tab and if it falls between the two dates.

Its not the fastest solution (takes about 15 second to check and write the outcome) but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be great to let us know, what you have done so far. I think the easiest way for a beginner is to just use two loops. One for the calculation and one for the projects tab.

Then you can start to develop your functionality. Use a "row counter" for each worksheet and iterate trough the rows. Here is an example pseudo code:

```
Dim lRowCountCalc as Long
Dim lRowCountPrj as Long
lRowCountCalc = 1
lRowCountPrj = 1

do
    do
        If Table2.Range("A" & lRowCountPrj).Value = Table1.Range("E" & lRowCountPrj).Value Then
            If ... dates are equal
                'Do some stuff
            End if
        End If
    lRowCountPrj = lRowCountPrj +1
    Loop Until lRowCountPrj = 5000 Or Table2.Range("A" & lRowCountPrj).text = ""
lRowCountCalc = lRowCountCalc +1
Loop Until lRowCountCalc = 5000 Or Table1.Range("A" & lRowCountCalc).text = ""
```

Just check for each employee number in calculation if there is a the same number in the current row in projects. If so, do your checks and fill in the information you need. If there is more than one project, you will find it also because all rows will be checked.

But be careful. This is very expensive because this code iterates for each row in projects over all rows in calculation. But for the beginning I would do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your screenshots appear to be Excel for Windows consider an SQL solution using Windows' JET/ACE Engine (.dll files) as you simply need to join the two worksheets with a `WHERE` clause for date filter. In this approach you avoid any need for looping and use of arrays/collections.

To integrate below, add a new worksheet called *RESULTS* as SQL queries on workbooks are read-only operations and do not update existing data. A `LEFT JOIN` is used to keep all records in *Calculations* regardless of matches in *Projects* but matched data will populate in empty columns. *Results* should structurally replicate *Calculations*. Adjust column names in `SELECT`, `ON`, and `WHERE` clauses as required (as I cannot clearly read column names from screenshots). Finally, a very important item: be sure date columns are formatted as Date type.

```
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String 
Dim i As Integer

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' OPEN DB CONNECTION 
strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _ ' 
                   & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx;"

conn.Open strConnection

' OPEN QUERY RECRDSET 
strSQL = "SELECT t1.*, t2.[Project] AS [Which Project], t2.[Customer] As [Which Customer]," _
          & "    t2.[Start], t2.[End planned], t2.[Hours per week]" _
          & " FROM [Calculation$A$3:$D$1048576] t1" _ 
          & " LEFT JOIN [Projects$A$3:$J$1048576] t2" _ 
          & " ON t1.EmployeeNum = t2.EmployeeNum" _
          & " WHERE t1.[Date] BETWEEN t2.Start AND t2.[End planned];"

rst.Open strSQL, conn

' COLUMNS 
For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(3, i) = 
   rst.Fields(i - 1).Name 
Next i

' DATA ROWS 
Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close 
conn.Close

Set rst = Nothing 
Set conn = Nothing
```